# Security Risk From Files Permissions

Tags: apache, ssh, permissions, command

Today i have made multiple searchs on Google and Stackoverflow about which permissions we need to our files in a web server. I have found more than 20 results "only in the community of StackOverFlow", and all from them have totally differents answers and ideas. There are which ones that says that folders from a public directory need to have 755 permissions and files 755, then there is another group which say that all files and folders must have 644 or 655 permissions.

Most of the answers talks about totally different permissions, arguing that the permission which they talk is the correct one, but when i see the other answers get more confuse because they do not explain why is it more safety for the owner.

In my case my web folders has 777 permissions and also my php files, this is correct? If is not correct, i would like to listen your explanations and recommendations, also a solution to change all the files and diretories to the correct permission. Thanks

Comment: The general rule in security is to give the least possible to provide the service.  If your apache runs under user ABCD, then only ABCD should have read access to files.  And read + execute on the sub-directories.  That is it.  Less is best when it comes to security.  Some requirements might involve group permissions.  That is ok if so desired.  I make a rule never to put "others" access.  So never 666 or 777.  The "highest" I will go is 640 for files and 750 for directories.  Without your specific requirements, we can only guess as to your best scenario might be.

Comment: To change permissions, do this in your web files directory: `find . -type f -exec chmod 640 {} \; -print` and `find . -type d -exec chmod 750 {} \; -print`.  These will recurse down your directories and set all permissions as desired.  **careful** do not do this in `/` or a high level directory on your system!  Only from the top directory where your web files reside.